How to get in Root Path end point in Quarkus
I couldn't get in @Path("/") whatever i try. I located META-INF/resources to static/ and index.html resides in /static/index.html now. So, static flow is not problem. What i m trying to achieve is redirect to root path to another address. To do this, i tried a ContainerRequestFilter, not worked and also tried a custom controller with @Path("/"), that didnt work neither. the only thing i got is "Resource not found". whatever i ve tried, i couldnt get in root "/".
How can something so simple not work?
Just in case, i tried setting" quarkus.http.root-path=/" , but nothing changed
That s my simple controller which is supposed to catch the request coming in http://localhost:8080

@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class DirectorController {

    @GET
    public Response redirectRoot() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
                .header("Location", "some path").build();
    }

}


I found what I missed. There is @ApplicationPath("api") in the project. So quarkus.http.root-path starts with /api, but when I tried setting quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/, the app root overrides it, I think, because non-application-root-path can't include the app-root. That would be nonsense.
In short, quarkus.http.root-path >= quarkus.http.non-application-root-path.
If we try the opposite of this, quarkus.http.root-path will overide the other.
